# Is it poor style to include a .cu file in another .cu file?

Tags: cuda

I know for `C++` it is bad form to include a `.cpp` file in another `.cpp` file. Are the rules different for CUDA?

For example, I have a file called `Earth.cu` with a bunch of `__constant__` values in it defining the geometry of the earth.

In my main `.cu` file (with the `__global__` entry point), I'm including the `Earth.cu` at the top.

Is it considered poor form to include a `.cu` file in another `.cu` file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd recommend to rename `Earth.cu` into `Earth.cuh`: that's the way I've seen it done in several projects. It makes it distinct both from normal headers (`.h`) and compilable `.cu` files.